# Ubuntu is taking long time to boot

Tags: boot

I haven't installed anything else, But it takes 92 seconds to boot. In the beginning it states "booting in insecure mode". What can I do to get it to boot in 7-10 seconds like I've seen in the Ubuntu commercial?

I have a Toshiba e45-b4200 with i5 CPU and 6 GB RAM. I removed the pre-installed Windows 8.1 system and replaced it altogether with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Here is the output of `dmesg`:

```
[    0.567633] brd: module loaded
[    0.568152] loop: module loaded
[    0.568336] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    0.568340] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    0.568341] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky 
[    0.568402] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    0.568441] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.568450] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.568544] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.568549] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.568560] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: debug port 2
[    0.572470] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    0.572484] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: irq 23, io mem 0xf7f1b000
[    0.583015] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.583059] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.583061] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.583063] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.583065] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-33-generic ehci_hcd
[    0.583066] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    0.583197] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.583202] hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[    0.583354] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    0.583366] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.583373] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.583388] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    0.583398] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.583524] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.583529] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.583609] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    0.583626] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: irq 56 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.583684] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.583686] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.583687] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.583689] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-33-generic xhci_hcd
[    0.583691] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.583916] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.583929] hub 2-0:1.0: 9 ports detected
[    0.586349] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.586352] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    0.586375] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    0.586376] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.586377] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.586379] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.16.0-33-generic xhci_hcd
[    0.586380] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.586542] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.586549] hub 3-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    0.587649] i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:PS2K,PNP0f13:PS2M] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
[    0.589471] i8042: Detected active multiplexing controller, rev 1.1
[    0.590431] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
[    0.590435] serio: i8042 AUX0 port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    0.590454] serio: i8042 AUX1 port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    0.590469] serio: i8042 AUX2 port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    0.590485] serio: i8042 AUX3 port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
[    0.590742] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.591042] rtc_cmos 00:01: RTC can wake from S4
[    0.591195] rtc_cmos 00:01: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[    0.591232] rtc_cmos 00:01: alarms up to one month, y3k, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[    0.591283] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    0.591385] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.27.0-ioctl (2013-10-30) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    0.591406] Intel P-state driver initializing.
[    0.591417] Intel pstate controlling: cpu 0
[    0.591453] Intel pstate controlling: cpu 1
[    0.591464] Intel pstate controlling: cpu 2
[    0.591506] Intel pstate controlling: cpu 3
[    0.591534] Consider also installing thermald for improved thermal control.
[    0.591538] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    0.591542] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
[    0.595369] TCP: cubic registered
[    0.595477] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    0.595701] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.595713] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    0.595987] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    0.597024] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 2526eefe32c958b4cd85ca5fbfebeda175d1b218'
[    0.597043] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.598569] Key type trusted registered
[    0.600286] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
[    0.601186] Key type encrypted registered
[    0.601193] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    0.601197] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    0.601211] evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1
[    0.601577]   Magic number: 7:990:184
[    0.601616] thermal LNXTHERM:00: hash matches
[    0.601630] acpi device:43: hash matches
[    0.601694] rtc_cmos 00:01: setting system clock to 2015-03-24 15:09:49 UTC (1427209789)
[    0.601747] BIOS EDD facility v0.16 2004-Jun-25, 0 devices found
[    0.601748] EDD information not available.
[    0.601825] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[    0.611681] ACPI: Battery Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    0.612674] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1352K (ffffffff81d1c000 - ffffffff81e6e000)
[    0.612677] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 12288k
[    0.614134] Freeing unused kernel memory: 560K (ffff880002774000 - ffff880002800000)
[    0.615098] Freeing unused kernel memory: 500K (ffff880002b83000 - ffff880002c00000)
[    0.616539] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x7c on isa0060/serio0).
[    0.616543] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes 7c ' to make it known.
[    0.627246] systemd-udevd[116]: starting version 204
[    0.639386] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.639389] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.649209] r8169 Gigabit Ethernet driver 2.3LK-NAPI loaded
[    0.649216] r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    0.651519] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
[    0.651652] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: irq 57 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.655445] r8169 0000:03:00.0: irq 58 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.655635] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g at 0xffffc90000022000, 00:71:c2:13:df:0a, XID 0c000880 IRQ 58
[    0.655638] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    0.667096] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 2 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
[    0.667101] ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq led clo only pio slum part deso sadm sds apst 
[    0.667492] scsi0 : ahci
[    0.667625] scsi1 : ahci
[    0.667689] ata1: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m2048@0xf7f1a000 port 0xf7f1a100 irq 57
[    0.667691] ata2: DUMMY
[    0.816439] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x7c on isa0060/serio0).
[    0.816444] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes 7c ' to make it known.
[    0.895394] usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    0.987402] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.016631] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x7c on isa0060/serio0).
[    1.016636] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes 7c ' to make it known.
[    1.019140] ata1.00: ATA-8: TOSHIBA MQ01ABD075, AX1P4M, max UDMA/100
[    1.019145] ata1.00: 1465149168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32), AA
[    1.021092] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    1.021307] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      TOSHIBA MQ01ABD0 4M   PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    1.021732] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1465149168 512-byte logical blocks: (750 GB/698 GiB)
[    1.021767] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    1.021770] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[    1.021772] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[    1.021781] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[    1.024755] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=07dc
[    1.024759] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.142879]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
[    1.143223] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    1.191606] usb 2-6: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.216763] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x7c on isa0060/serio0).
[    1.216767] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes 7c ' to make it known.
[    1.365444] usb 2-6: New USB device found, idVendor=13d3, idProduct=5652
[    1.365448] usb 2-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    1.365450] usb 2-6: Product: TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD
[    1.365452] usb 2-6: Manufacturer: Azurewave
[    1.365454] usb 2-6: SerialNumber: NULL
[    1.426603] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x7c on isa0060/serio0).
[    1.426607] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes 7c ' to make it known.
[    1.479862] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.527784] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 2394.456 MHz
[    1.603461] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.616293] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    1.616297] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.616702] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.616777] hub 1-1:1.0: 8 ports detected
[    1.629047] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x7c on isa0060/serio0).
[    1.629055] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes 7c ' to make it known.
[    1.888259] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    1.983417] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[    1.983421] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.983423] usb 1-1.1: Product: USB Receiver
[    1.983425] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.204781] random: init urandom read with 101 bits of entropy available
[    2.528853] Switched to clocksource tsc
[    2.571107] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    2.607710] psmouse serio4: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126800, board id: 2987, fw id: 1595020
[    2.607717] psmouse serio4: synaptics: Toshiba Satellite E45-B detected, limiting rate to 40pps.
[    2.644878] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio4/input/input11
[    4.496692] Adding 6199292k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:6199292k FS
[    5.110143] systemd-udevd[304]: starting version 204
[    5.770108] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    5.856627] wmi: Mapper loaded
[    5.862766] toshiba_bluetooth: Detected Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device - installing RFKill handler
[    5.862870] toshiba_bluetooth: Re-enabling Toshiba Bluetooth
[    5.927819] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    6.047236] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 59 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.107596] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[    6.174045] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[    6.392242] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    6.405816] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[    6.415891] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[    6.415905] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    6.415906] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.415912] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.415913] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.415919] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.444932] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    6.497895] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    6.512590] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710010002030d00
[    6.624679] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.2.3.d.bseq
[    6.667616] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux, in-tree:
[    6.667619] Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation
[    6.667666] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.667800] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 60 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.694473] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[    6.694478] checking generic (e0000000 7f0000) vs hw (e0000000 10000000)
[    6.694480] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[    6.694524] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[    6.694610] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    6.716035] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 61 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.716047] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    6.716048] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    6.716077] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[    6.732751] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[    6.736676] [drm] VBT doesn't support DRRS
[    6.755962] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 25.228.9.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.796758] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    6.796839] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    6.796859] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    6.796861] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
[    6.808203] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    6.808285] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input12
[    6.808376] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[    7.278097] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    7.282924] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[    7.282927] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[    7.282929] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[    7.282932] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    7.282934] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    7.282936] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    7.282937] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    7.282939] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[    7.371719] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    7.442266] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    7.442270] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    7.526523] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input2
[    7.582670] input: Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1028 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:C52B.0004/input/input13
[    7.582855] logitech-djdevice 0003:046D:C52B.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:1028] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1:1
[    7.587558] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.587699] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.587855] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 62 for MSI/MSI-X
[    7.595044] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: irq 63 for MSI/MSI-X
[    7.615331] sound hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[    7.615334] sound hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    7.615336] sound hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    7.615337] sound hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    7.615338] sound hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[    7.615340] sound hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x19
[    7.615341] sound hdaudioC1D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[    7.620809] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input14
[    7.621082] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input15
[    7.621229] input: HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/sound/card0/input16
[    7.629814] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3160, REV=0x164
[    7.629864] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.630086] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[    7.741667] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    7.741672] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    7.741674] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    7.741677] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[    7.773563] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    7.807446] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input17
[    7.808178] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card1/input18
[    7.824964] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
[    8.269557] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD (13d3:5652)
[    8.272061] input: TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/input/input19
[    8.272163] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    8.272166] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[    9.517288] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   11.257075] init: failsafe main process (680) killed by TERM signal
[   14.154778] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   14.154783] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   14.154792] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   14.277817] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209803.160:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=813 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.277825] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209803.160:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=813 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.278363] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209803.164:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=813 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.461726] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   14.461736] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   14.461742] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   14.910532] init: cups main process (832) killed by HUP signal
[   14.910543] init: cups main process ended, respawning
[   17.550503] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209806.432:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=892 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.550512] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209806.432:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="chromium" pid=892 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.550839] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209806.432:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="chromium" pid=892 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.552347] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209806.432:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" pid=896 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.552355] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209806.432:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*" pid=896 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.552359] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209806.432:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="pxgsettings" pid=896 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.552364] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209806.432:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="sanitized_helper" pid=896 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.214359] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   18.214578] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   18.225599] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   18.431540] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[   18.431588] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   18.716480] init: alsa-restore main process (997) terminated with status 99
[   25.676234] wlan0: authenticate with 00:21:d8:36:3a:00
[   25.678595] wlan0: send auth to 00:21:d8:36:3a:00 (try 1/3)
[   25.685781] wlan0: authenticated
[   25.687318] wlan0: associate with 00:21:d8:36:3a:00 (try 1/3)
[   25.697114] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:21:d8:36:3a:00 (capab=0x401 status=0 aid=212)
[   25.700041] wlan0: associated
[   25.700061] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   25.701058] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:21:d8:36:3a:00 by local choice (Reason: 2=PREV_AUTH_NOT_VALID)
[   25.708772] wlan0: authenticate with 00:21:d8:36:3a:00
[   25.710311] wlan0: send auth to 00:21:d8:36:3a:00 (try 1/3)
[   25.710709] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   25.712251] wlan0: authenticated
[   25.713252] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   25.713255] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   25.713257] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   25.713259] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   25.713261] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   25.713263] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   25.713264] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   25.713266] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   25.715301] wlan0: associate with 00:21:d8:36:3a:00 (try 1/3)
[   25.721220] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:21:d8:36:3a:00 (capab=0x401 status=0 aid=213)
[   25.722022] wlan0: associated
[   26.018067] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Time Event end notification failure
[   26.086999] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   26.093896] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1170) terminated with status 1
[   26.093908] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   35.738639] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:21:d8:36:3a:00 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   35.741489] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   35.743325] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   35.743329] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   35.743330] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   35.743332] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   35.743333] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   35.743335] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   35.743336] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   35.743337] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   45.286689] audit_printk_skb: 123 callbacks suppressed
[   45.286693] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209834.144:53): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=2039 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   45.286701] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209834.144:54): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2039 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   45.287069] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209834.144:55): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=2039 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   65.368360] compiz[1856]: segfault at 65756c6176 ip 00007f103e0a4d84 sp 00007fff6aefa370 error 4 in libdbusmenu-glib.so.4.0.12[7f103e09d000+1a000]
[  112.076949] wlan0: authenticate with 00:0f:34:a0:4f:10
[  112.078607] wlan0: send auth to 00:0f:34:a0:4f:10 (try 1/3)
[  112.080114] wlan0: authenticated
[  112.081012] wlan0: associate with 00:0f:34:a0:4f:10 (try 1/3)
[  112.083874] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:0f:34:a0:4f:10 (capab=0x401 status=0 aid=73)
[  112.087287] wlan0: associated
[  112.737109] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209901.540:56): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=2727 comm="nm-dhcp-client." lport=52225 family="inet" sock_type="dgram" protocol=17
[  112.737123] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209901.540:57): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=2727 comm="nm-dhcp-client." lport=43333 family="inet6" sock_type="dgram" protocol=17
[  123.847277] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209912.644:58): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=3013 comm="nm-dhcp-client." lport=52225 family="inet" sock_type="dgram" protocol=17
[  123.847288] audit: type=1400 audit(1427209912.644:59): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=3013 comm="nm-dhcp-client." lport=43333 family="inet6" sock_type="dgram" protocol=17
[  175.171576] systemd-hostnamed[3247]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[  305.785103] init: upstart-udev-bridge main process (294) terminated with status 1
[  305.785113] init: upstart-udev-bridge main process ended, respawning
[  305.785198] init: upstart-socket-bridge main process (534) terminated with status 1
[  305.785205] init: upstart-socket-bridge main process ended, respawning
[  305.785267] init: upstart-file-bridge main process (704) terminated with status 1
[  305.785273] init: upstart-file-bridge main process ended, respawning
[  489.994877] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210278.409:60): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=12145 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  490.231588] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210278.645:61): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=12184 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  491.630579] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210280.041:62): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=12204 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  491.630823] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210280.041:63): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=12204 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  491.676616] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210280.089:64): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=12241 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  491.676623] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210280.089:65): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=12241 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  491.677084] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210280.089:66): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=12241 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  500.400990] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210288.805:67): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=12242 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[  500.400998] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210288.805:68): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=12242 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[  500.401003] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210288.805:69): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=12242 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[  500.401008] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210288.805:70): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=12242 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[  500.401012] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210288.805:71): apparmor="DENIED" operation="signal" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=12242 comm="cupsd" requested_mask="send" denied_mask="send" signal=term peer="unconfined"
[  516.852809] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210305.245:72): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=16192 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  516.864345] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210305.257:73): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="sanitized_helper" pid=16192 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  516.865139] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210305.257:74): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=16192 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  516.879928] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210305.273:75): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="sanitized_helper" pid=16192 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  516.880497] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210305.273:76): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer" pid=16192 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  516.895850] audit: type=1400 audit(1427210305.289:77): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="sanitized_helper" pid=16192 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: I have a similar hardware and software configuration, and my laptop takes 4 to 5 seconds to boot and to show the login interface.
Maybe your machine have a HDD disk.

Comment: 750gb hard disk. But 92 seconds on a modern laptop its by no means low end(http://www.bestbuy.com/site/toshiba-satellite-14-laptop-intel-core-i5-6gb-memory-750gb-hard-drive-satin-gold/6863116.p?id=1219241420808). I was leaning toward bootup since 8.1 was preinstalled and i turned off the safety boot maybe it still thinks to load windows but since its not there it look for ubuntu 2ndly. I am not sure but it prob has a timeout during the boot somehow.

Comment: Are you booting in UEFI mode or legacy?  Looking at the dmesg output, do you see 5-30 second gaps in the times (look at what is causing the timeout).  Do you shutdown cleanly?

Comment: UEFI. I see around 10sec gaps but once though.  heres a quick dmesg output of the first big gap synaptics: Toshiba Satellite E45-B detected, limiting rate to 40pps.
[    2.660871] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[    2.666566] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio4/input/input11
[    9.037749] usb 2-7: USB disconnect, device number 4
[   12.392951] Adding 6199292k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:6199292k FS

Comment: I would look at last two entries first. Not sure what this is: name="third_party" pid=3985 and error on nss-myhostname not installed?

Comment: I have never used Linux until recently and ubuntu is my first flavour. But can follow instructions exactly as listed. This has been here for a while and no support in terms of what to do, should I repost in a different location instead of boot in askubuntu ? I am impatient simply because of my boot time is as long as they were 20 years ago and being used to android Linux and even windows 8 boot up times make this experience of Ubuntu not a good one at all.

Comment: It seems to spend large amounts of time setting up your wlan. Try deactivating it and see if that helps? If it does, you can configure it to not start until you login. But of course, you'll want to fix the real issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your WLAN that makes other services wait for a long time because they require network to be ready. If you deactivate system-wide WLAN, it won't start at boot and you should get a greatly improved boot time. Then you'll have to connect at login instead.

Of course, you'll want to find out what's causing the issues and fix that, but simply deactivating wlan should solve the specific issue of slow boot.